# Testing the typesafe enum pattern in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, testing, nunit

I am utilizing the "typesafe enum pattern"

```
public class Level
{
    public static readonly Level Low = new Level(0, "Low");
    public static readonly Level Medium = new Level(1, "Medium");
    public static readonly Level High = new Level(2, "High");

    private int _value;
    private string name;

    private Level(int value, string name)
    {
        _value=value;
        _name=name;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I need to create an invalid Level which I do with reflection.

```
int id = -1;
string value = "invalid";
var constructor = typeof(Level).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {typeof(int), typeof(string)}, null);
var invalidLevel = (Level)constructor.Invoke(new object[] {id, value});
```

Using reflection to access the private constructor seems.... wrong to me. Is there a better way to make an invalid Level?

Comment: I really don't see why you want to validate an invalid `Level` using reflection? It seems very overkill to me. If you have total control over the library (ie it's not used elsewhere), this is will never happen, unless you do it yourself. If not, the users of your library know that creating an object with a private constructor is outside of the bound of your library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For testing purposes I need to create an invalid Level

Why? The point of the enum pattern here is to *stop* there from ever being an invalid level.

Trying to test this being broken is like trying to test that a method is type-safe by calling it via reflection with the wrong number of arguments. Basically, you shouldn't be trying to test this path IMO.

One path you probably *do* want to test for any code which receives a `Level` is that it handles a null value appropriately (e.g. by throwing `ArgumentNullException`).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a model that uses Level as a field. That model gets mapped from the database in a way that I cannot control. It has just happened where the mapping created.... a null. Yes, you nailed it. Talking to the duck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is about testing the public method/properties of a class (i.e. exercising the public API). As far as your class do not expose public ctor, you shouldn't need a test for that.

Comment: You might still wanna write a test or two. Better that wondering why a property is not setting or some other silly mistake.